# Work with and change the layout of an csv file in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I read a csv data with pandas and now I would like to change the layout of my dataset. My dataset from excel looks like this:

[image]

I run the code with `df = pd.read_csv(Location2)`

This is what I get:

[image]

I would like to have a separated column for `time` and `Watt` and their values.

I looked at the documentation but I couldn't find something to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as if you'd need to set up the correct delimiter that separates the two fields. Try adding `delimiter=";"` to the parameters

Answer (score 0):

Use [read_excel](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html)

```
df = pd.read_excel(Location2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need parameter `sep` in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html), because default separator is `,`:

```
df = pd.read_csv(Location2, sep=';')
```

Sample:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO

temp=u"""time;Watt
0;00:00:00;50
1;01:00:00;45
2;02:00:00;40
3;00:03:00;35"""
#after testing replace 'StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), sep=";")
print (df)
       time  Watt
0  00:00:00    50
1  01:00:00    45
2  02:00:00    40
3  00:03:00    35
```

Then is possible convert `time` column [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html):

```
df['time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['time'])
print (df)
      time  Watt
0 00:00:00    50
1 01:00:00    45
2 02:00:00    40
3 00:03:00    35

print (df.dtypes)
time    timedelta64[ns]
Watt              int64
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! But the StringIO command didn't work for me.

Comment: I think you dont notice comment above `#after testing replace 'StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'` ;)

Comment: Sorry, you are right! I forgot that. It worked now. Thanks

Comment: Hmmm, only one answer can be accepted. Btw`sep` is used more, because shorter. `delimiter` vs `sep`. ;) [delimiter](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpandas%5D+delimiter%3D) vs [sep](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpandas%5D+sep%3D)

Comment: exactly. Coders are lazy, so prefer `sep`, becasue less typing ;)